# Impossible to find a lambda paper

Tags: scheme

I read the lambda papers, however it is impossible for me to find the 8th paper from [this list](http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html), namely the thesis of Steele, named

```
G.L.Steele, Jr. "Compiler Optimization Based on Viewing LAMBDA as RENAME + GOTO".
AI: An MIT Perspective. 1980
```

Can somebody help me find a place where I can buy this paper from ?

Comment: It's in volume 2 of "Artificial Intelligence: an MIT perspective".

Comment: @molbdnilo  I thought the same but on the tab `table of contents` I cannot see it.  http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1056640 . Where do you see it ?

Comment: Actually you are right.  On abebooks I see a comment about the presence of this paper in AI-anMITPersp.   Here https://www.abebooks.fr/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=14471559903&searchurl=tn%3Dartificial%2Bintelligence%2Bperspective%2Bunderstanding%26sortby%3D17

Comment: The paper [Rabbit: A compiler for Scheme](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/6913/AITR-474.pdf) ([list of Lambda papers](https://research.scheme.org/lambda-papers/)) mentions that it is a "Revised version of a dissertation submitted under the title 'Compiler Optimizaiton Based on Viewing LAMBDA as RENAME plus GOTO'".

Comment: @NgahyBe  yes, one is the continuation of the other...  or takes some ideas from the older one.  A better paper about optimizations is Orbit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the book that contains the article.  The article is one of the [original lambda papers](https://web.archive.org/web/20180708092726/http://library.readscheme.org/page1.html).

> Artificial Intelligence: An MIT Perspective: Understanding Vision, Manipulation and Productivity Technology, Computer Design and Symbol Manipulation (Artificial Intelligence Series) (Volume 2)

[image: lambda-steele]